# Can I return multiple Pairs from a map feeding into a hash?

Tags: raku, feed-operator

I'm trying to create a hash that looks up by key or value. To look up both ways, I want the values to be keys (with values that are their keys).

```
<
H He
>
    ==> map( {
        state $n = 0; $n++;
        $n     => $_.Str,
        $_.Str => $n
         } )
    ==> my %elements;

%elements.perl.say;

%elements{2}.WHAT.say;
```

This gives me this weird thing:

```
{"1\tH H\t2" => $(2 => "He", :He(2))}
(Any)
```

With only one pair, it's fine:

```
<
H He
>
    ==> map( {
        state $n = 0; $n++;
        $n     => $_.Str
         } )
    ==> my %elements;

%elements.perl.say;

%elements{2}.WHAT.say;
```

Now I get what I want, but without the reverse pair:

```
{"1" => "H", "2" => "He"}
(Str)
```

Comment: I would use `map( { ++$ => ~$_ } )` or `<H He> Z=> 1..*` to create the initial set of Pairs.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your `map` returns a sequence of [`List`](https://docs.perl6.org/type/List) values that each contain two [`Pair`](https://docs.perl6.org/type/Pair) values.
Feeding this to the hash won't automatically flatten it, and each `List` becomes a key or value of the hash.

There are several ways to get it to do what you want:

### Using `flat`

You can use the built-in [`flat`](https://docs.perl6.org/routine/flat) function to flatten the result of the `map`, so that the hash receives a sequence of `Pair`s:

```
<H He>
==> map {
    (state $n)++;
    +$n => ~$_,
    ~$_ => +$n
}\
==> flat()
==> my %elements;

%elements.say;          # {1 => H, 2 => He, H => 1, He => 2}
%elements{2}.WHAT.say;  # (Str)
```

Both `map` and `flat` return lazy sequences, so this is (in theory) memory-efficient even if the list of elements is large.

- **Side note:** I've also written `+$n` instead of `$n` because the `=>` Pair construction operator (like the `,` List construction operator) doesn't "decontainerize" its arguments - if you give it an item container such as a `$` variable, it'll bind to that directly instead of the value contained in it, which causes the next `$n++` to also affect the `Pair` returned from the previous iteration. Giving the pair construction operator a value expression instead of a variable, avoids this.

### Using `slip`

[`slip`](https://docs.perl6.org/routine/slip) is the inside-out version of `flat`:

```
<H He>
==> map {
    (state $n)++;
    slip
        +$n => ~$_,
        ~$_ => +$n
}\
==> my %elements;
```

Each iteration of the `map` now returns a value of type [`Slip`](https://docs.perl6.org/type/Slip), which is just like `List` except that it automatically dissolved into any parent list it becomes part of.

### Refactoring

If you're not tied to your particular approach, here are two potentially clearer ways to generate the same hash:

```
my @keys = 1..*;
my @values = <H He>;
my %elements = flat (@keys Z=> @values), (@values Z=> @keys);
```

Or:

```
my %elements = 1..* Z=> <H He>;
push %elements, %elements.invert;
```

([`Z`](https://docs.perl6.org/language/operators.html#infix_Z) is the "zip" meta-operator)